# Why does AWS API Gateway not support VPCs?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, networking, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have just read following [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-with-vpc-endpoints-via-aws-lambda/)

And I really don't get why the AWS API Gateway doesn't support VPCs out of the box and we have to proxy all the requests through a lambda function?

Does anyone have an idea about why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I never found any AWS official statement about this matter, I strongly believe that accessing private resources (VPCs, subnets) from an always public entity (as is API Gateway) would require much more effort (testing) regarding the product security.

I don't believe their plan is to keep it like this forever, though. From this same article you linked, they state (my emphasis):

> **Today**, Amazon API Gateway cannot directly integrate with endpoints
>   that live within a VPC without internet access.

My guess is that "***tomorrow***" API Gateway access to private resources will exist and, yes, our lives will be easier (and cheaper, btw).

In the end of the day, and given that my assumption is right, I believe it was the right decision: launch a useful (but more limited) version first and learn with it.

**EDIT:** Since 2017 November, API Gateway integrates with private VPCs. https://aws.amazon.com/pt/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-endpoint-integrations-with-private-vpcs/

Comment: definitely. the ability to proxy vpc resources works nicely for many use cases. looking forward to this feature if/when implemented.